# How to change popover-placement value from scope in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, popover

I am using bs-popover.

I hover on a icon, the popup is always displayed bottom-left.
The problem is when the icon is at the end of the screen, the popup is not visible (since placement is bottom-left). In this case, I want to bring the popup on "top-left".

Please guide me. How to change the data-placement value dynamically?
This is my code:

```
<div bs-popover delay="200" data-placement="{{getPlacement(i)}}" data-trigger="hover" 
     data-content-template="popover.html" style="position: absolute; top:-2px;left:5px;">

    <i class="fa fa-sm fa-thumb-tack" ng:show="i.showIcon"></i>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change popover placement dynamycally, `bs-popover` do not support it, but you can predefine different placement types like so http://jsfiddle.net/bn9qv607/1/

Comment: I see that the placement is updated with 'bottom-left' / 'top-left' but when i hover on the icon, the popover is on right. It is applying class right.